# Return array object

Tags: c++

I am trying to return an object array and assign to another object array in main function.

Function:

```
Student* readFromFile( string fileName ){
    Student a[SIZE];
    int x;
    int y;
    double z;
    ifstream dosya(fileName);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        dosya >> x >> y >> z;
        Student s(x, y, z);
        a[i] = s;
    }
    return a;
}
```

In main:

```
Student* students;
students = readFromFile( "Students");
printStudents( students );
```

And my header:

```
class Student{
public:
    Student(){};
    Student( int v, int m, double k ){
        studentID = v;
        year = m;
        GPA = k;
    }
    int getstudentID(){
        return studentID;
    }
    int getYear(){
        return year;
    }
    double getGPA(){
        return GPA;
    }

private:
    int studentID; 
    int year; 
    double GPA;
};
```

When I run the program it returns null values, but if I print `a[SIZE]` it returns quite values.
I cannot change the header file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A C programmer who hasn't *quite* fully moved to C++ is known as a C+ programmer, you don't want to become one of those since it just looks like a typo on your CV :-) Therefore my advice is to *embrace* C++, and start using `std::vector` - things will become *so* much easier.

Comment: *I am trying to return an object array and assign to another object array in main function* -- Given your description, use `std::array<Student, SIZE> a;` instead of pointers.  That's the purpose of `std::array` so that it can be easily passed/returned between functions and assigned.